# Issue with Ubuntu Landscape quick start

Tags: landscape

I have setup a fresh  ubuntu 18 server and following the quickstart guide to create a landscape server.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:landscape/19.10
sudo apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart
```

Install has not come back with any errors, but the final part of the install is to start the the services and this is where is fails, saying permission denied. The other services, such as postrgres and rabbit have started fine. Output below :

`update@srvubu18update:~$ sudo lsctl status`

```
== landscape-appserver ==

● landscape-appserver.service - LSB: Enable Landscape frontend UI

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/landscape-appserver; generated)

   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-04-22 07:16:26 UTC; 4min 13s ago

     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

  Process: 1195 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/landscape-appserver start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 

Apr 22 07:16:00 srvubu18update systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Enable Landscape frontend UI...

Apr 22 07:16:01 srvubu18update landscape-appserver[1195]:  * Checking database schema

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-appserver[1195]:    ...done.

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-appserver[1195]:  * Starting Landscape standalone appserver 1

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-appserver[1195]: start-stop-daemon: unable to start /opt/canonical/landscape/landscape (Permission denied)

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-appserver[1195]:    ...fail!

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-appserver.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-appserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Enable Landscape frontend UI.

== landscape-async-frontend ==

● landscape-async-frontend.service - LSB: Enable Landscape async frontend

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/landscape-async-frontend; generated)

   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-04-22 07:16:26 UTC; 4min 13s ago

     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

  Process: 1203 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/landscape-async-frontend start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 

Apr 22 07:16:00 srvubu18update systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Enable Landscape async frontend...

Apr 22 07:16:01 srvubu18update landscape-async-frontend[1203]:  * Checking database schema

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-async-frontend[1203]:    ...done.

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-async-frontend[1203]:  * Starting Landscape standalone async-frontend 1

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-async-frontend[1203]: start-stop-daemon: unable to start /opt/canonical/landscape/async-frontend (Permission denied)

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-async-frontend[1203]:    ...fail!

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-async-frontend.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-async-frontend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Enable Landscape async frontend.

== landscape-job-handler ==

● landscape-job-handler.service - LSB: Enable Landscape job handler

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/landscape-job-handler; generated)

   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-04-22 07:16:26 UTC; 4min 13s ago

     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

  Process: 1316 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/landscape-job-handler start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 

Apr 22 07:16:01 srvubu18update systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Enable Landscape job handler...

Apr 22 07:16:01 srvubu18update landscape-job-handler[1316]:  * Checking database schema

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-job-handler[1316]:    ...done.

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-job-handler[1316]:  * Starting Landscape standalone job-handler 1

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-job-handler[1316]: start-stop-daemon: unable to start /opt/canonical/landscape/job-handler (Permission denied)

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-job-handler.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-job-handler[1316]:    ...fail!

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-job-handler.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Enable Landscape job handler.

== landscape-msgserver ==

● landscape-msgserver.service - LSB: Enable Landscape message processing

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/landscape-msgserver; generated)

   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-04-22 07:16:26 UTC; 4min 13s ago

     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

  Process: 1148 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/landscape-msgserver start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 

Apr 22 07:16:00 srvubu18update systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Enable Landscape message processing...

Apr 22 07:16:01 srvubu18update landscape-msgserver[1148]:  * Checking database schema

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-msgserver[1148]:    ...done.

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-msgserver[1148]:  * Starting Landscape standalone message-server 1

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-msgserver[1148]: start-stop-daemon: unable to start /opt/canonical/landscape/message-server (Permission denied)

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-msgserver[1148]:    ...fail!

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-msgserver.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-msgserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Enable Landscape message processing.

== landscape-pingserver ==

● landscape-pingserver.service - LSB: Enable Landscape ping server

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/landscape-pingserver; generated)

   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-04-22 07:16:26 UTC; 4min 13s ago

     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

  Process: 1151 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/landscape-pingserver start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 

Apr 22 07:16:00 srvubu18update systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Enable Landscape ping server...

Apr 22 07:16:01 srvubu18update landscape-pingserver[1151]:  * Checking database schema

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-pingserver[1151]:    ...done.

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-pingserver[1151]:  * Starting Landscape standalone pingserver 1

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-pingserver[1151]: start-stop-daemon: unable to start /opt/canonical/landscape/pingserver (Permission denied)

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-pingserver[1151]:    ...fail!

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-pingserver.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-pingserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Enable Landscape ping server.

== landscape-api ==

● landscape-api.service - LSB: Enable Landscape API

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/landscape-api; generated)

   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-04-22 07:16:26 UTC; 4min 13s ago

     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

  Process: 1147 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/landscape-api start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 

Apr 22 07:16:00 srvubu18update systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Enable Landscape API...

Apr 22 07:16:01 srvubu18update landscape-api[1147]:  * Checking database schema

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-api[1147]:    ...done.

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-api[1147]:  * Starting Landscape standalone api 1

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-api[1147]: start-stop-daemon: unable to start /opt/canonical/landscape/api (Permission denied)

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-api[1147]:    ...fail!

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-api.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-api.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Enable Landscape API.

== landscape-package-upload ==

● landscape-package-upload.service - LSB: Enable Landscape Package Upload service

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/landscape-package-upload; generated)

   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-04-22 07:16:26 UTC; 4min 13s ago

     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

  Process: 1317 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/landscape-package-upload start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 

Apr 22 07:16:01 srvubu18update systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Enable Landscape Package Upload service...

Apr 22 07:16:01 srvubu18update landscape-package-upload[1317]:  * Checking database schema

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-package-upload[1317]:    ...done.

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-package-upload[1317]:  * Starting Landscape standalone package-upload 1

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-package-upload[1317]: start-stop-daemon: unable to start /opt/canonical/landscape/package-upload (Permission denied)

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-package-upload.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update landscape-package-upload[1317]:    ...fail!

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-package-upload.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Apr 22 07:16:26 srvubu18update systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Enable Landscape Package Upload service.

== landscape-package-search ==

● landscape-package-search.service - Landscape's Package Search daemon

   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/landscape-package-search.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-04-22 07:16:06 UTC; 4min 33s ago

  Process: 2171 ExecStartPre=/opt/canonical/landscape/landscape-schema-check (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

 

Apr 22 07:16:06 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-package-search.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.

Apr 22 07:16:06 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-package-search.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 20.

Apr 22 07:16:06 srvubu18update systemd[1]: Stopped Landscape's Package Search daemon.

Apr 22 07:16:06 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-package-search.service: Start request repeated too quickly.

Apr 22 07:16:06 srvubu18update systemd[1]: landscape-package-search.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Apr 22 07:16:06 srvubu18update systemd[1]: Failed to start Landscape's Package Search daemon.

== landscape-pppa-proxy ==

... Not enabled, skipping.
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Si

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist *snap* based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances do use a *yy* format there are none titled just Ubuntu 18.  Please clarify your release as there is no Ubuntu 18.  (Server could mean the main Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server release, or the specialist Ubuntu Core 18 which is intended for headless server systems, esp. in the cloud)

Comment: Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions ?

Comment: Please adjust your question which still states Ubuntu 18 implying a *snap* only server/system, which most will stay away from as most people use *yy.mm* format releases. You've also mentioned using an *eoan* source on *bionic* meaning your system is likely *fraken* and no longer *bionic*.  I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to evaluate the state of your system.